# Do powerline adapters work optimally across RCDs?

Tags: powerline-networking

Do powerline adapters work if using them in a house on different rings? Does it matter if the rings are separated by an RCD?

I seem to get conflicting advice on this. Definitive answer would be great!

Comment: On different rings it will probably work, but different *phases* is unlikely. Only a comment because I have no definitive proof.

Comment: I have no evidence to back this up, but i think the biggest issue would purely be attenuation. That is to say, the more "kit" there is between the plugs, the slower the connection will become.